# Custom queries in Android sqlite and Primary key on multiple colums

Tags: java, android, iphone, objective-c, sqlite

Hi guys i am trying to use a custom sqlite queries in android.

i am experiencing following problems :

1- My primary key consists of multiple columns. How can i place data in Db sqlite in android? Does

```
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
```

This process will work?

2- Custom queries

```
String queryString = "SELECT MAX(accountId) FROM MAAccounts WHERE userId = ? AND accountType = ?";
```

i want to pass two parameters

```
String userId, AccountType accountType
```

Note that userId  is string type and accoutType is int or AccountType.

Please tell me if this is possible in sqlite android to pass custom queries and arguments  or not? If so then how?

3- Also, in Iphone we use `FMD Database` library , is there any library which we can use in android just like Iphone one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For custom query use method:

```
db.rawQuery("MAX(accountId) FROM MAAccounts WHERE userId = ? AND accountType = ?", new String[]{value1,value2});
```

here value1 and value2 are values to be passed.

Comment: value1 and value2 are not string type. What should i do? One is string other one type is AccountType

Comment: just cast to String values, as dabtabase consider all values as Strings ultimately.

Comment: ok, what about other questions. If i have composite primary key then this query system will work? Do i have to add underscore anywhere?